# Nodejs: Cannot find module `nanoid`

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

When I try to compile my Typescript project (NestJS) I came across the following problem.

Some packages like `nanoid`, `cookie-parser` give error `Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid'`

The code where they used is below:

```
...
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
...
    const confirmToken = nanoid(32);
...
```

**Here are what I tried:**

1. I checked the `node_modules` directory. The package is there
   [image]
2. Tried to completely remove node_modules and package.json.lock.
3. Used v16.14.0, v17 versions of NodeJS
4. Used yarn and npm

None of these ways helped.

Again, this error happens with only certain packages.

What could be an issue?

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Is this in the terminal or in your IDE?

Comment: please share the error you are getting exactly, as well as your `package.json` file. it would be of great help

Comment: @JayMcDoniel This is the error that I'm getting when I try to run the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9guoflrsrkt5cy/img-2022-03-02-08-01-28.png?dl=0

Comment: @Gianluca posted the screenshot of error. And here is the package json: https://gist.github.com/efbdc41568b8dbd4dfd36de2470866e8

Comment: Are you running this locally? Is this happening in a docker container? Your package.json looks good from what I can see